# Ctrl+Shift+L not working

Tags: excel, excel-2010

in which a shortcut Ctrl+Shift+L mainly used for applying filter for selected cells, here in my excel this shortcut is not working, can anyone please help me in this

Comment: Can you post the first part of the sentence? The bit that goes before "in which"? You may want to use a few more words of description and explain how this relates to programming. If your problem is not about programming, go somewhere else.

Comment: Hi am using excel 2010, in which a shortcut Ctrl+Shift+L mainly used for applying filter for selected cells, here in my excel this shortcut is not working, can anyone please help me in this

Comment: Do you get an error when using the shortcut key?

Comment: not error the shortcut is not working at all